# Are script errors enabled by default in internet explorer?

Tags: script, internet-explorer

I'm developing a website and I'm using a program called [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to test by website on IE. However, when using IETester I get a script error about every 5 seconds, most likely due to some incompatibility in the code (no errors at all in Chrome or Firefox console). Perhaps these script errors are enabled by default in IETester since it's a debugging program, but are they enabled by default in the general consumer version of Internet Explorer 7 and 8?

Answer (score 1):

Use [IE Collection](http://utilu.com/IECollection/)

Utilu IE Collection contains multiple IE versions, which are standalone so they can be used at the same time. This is useful for web developers.

Utilu IE Collection supports both 32-bit and 64-bit versions (if available) of Microsoft Windows 98, 98 SE, ME, NT 4.0, 2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 2008 and 7.

Utilu IE Collection works best under the 32-bit version of Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 3 (whether or not in a virtual machine).

Version IE:

- Internet Explorer 1.0 (4.40.308)
- Internet Explorer 1.5 (0.1.0.10)
- Internet Explorer 2.01 (2.01.046)
- Internet Explorer 3.0 (3.0.1152)
- Internet Explorer 3.01 (3.01.2723)
- Internet Explorer 3.03 (3.03.2925)
- Internet Explorer 4.01 (4.72.3110.0)
- Internet Explorer 5.01 (5.00.3314.2100)
- Internet Explorer 5.5 (5.51.4807.2300)
- Internet Explorer 6.0 (6.00.2800.1106)
- Internet Explorer 6.0 (6.00.2900.2180)
- Internet Explorer 7.0 (7.00.5730.13)
- Internet Explorer 8.0 (8.00.6001.18702)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check that out. Doesn't exactly answer my question though....

Comment: @kpsuperplane Briefly, IETester often falls and mistakes do not always coincide with errors IE 5 ... 8. The best way to test - a virtual machine, or self-assembly of different versions of IE. Good luck!

Comment: Well, I tried out IE Collection. Sadly, it doesn't seem to be compatible with Windows 8 (my current OS) - nothing starts. Secondly, the program seems to have messed up my default Internet Explorer - that won't start either now. Looks like I'm going to have to reinstall IE10 before doing anything else.

Comment: @kpsuperplane Thank you. This week I will try to do the assembly with IE for my needs testing. Throw off the link at the end of the work, if interested. I have Windows 8 at virtual machine and test it too.

Comment: Sure. And just incase you encounter similar problems with Windows 8, I managed to fix IE with this [script](http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&cat=42&id=133&artlang=en) - I know it says IE8 but download the `ie8-rereg.all.zip` at the bottom and run all the cmd files as admin and things should work again.